# Meteorjs - What is the proper way to join collections on backend

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am very new to meteor.js and try to build an application with it. This time I wanted to try it over MEAN stack but at this point I am struggled to understand how to join two collection on server side...

I want very identical behaviour like mongodb `populate` to fetch some properties of inner document.

Let me tell you about my collection it is something like this

```
{
  name: 'Name',
  lastName: 'LastName',
  anotherObject: '_id of another object'
}
```

and another object has some fields

```
{
  neededField1: 'asd',
  neededField2: 'zxc',
  notNeededField: 'qwe'
}
```

So whenever I made a REST call to retrieve the first object I want it contains only *neededFields* of inner object so I need join them at backend but I cannot find a proper way to do it.

So far while searching it I saw some packages here is the list

1. [Meteor Collections Helper](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers)
2. [Publish with Relations](https://github.com/svasva/meteor-publish-with-relations)
3. [Reactive joins in Meteor (article)](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/)
4. [Joins in Meteor.js (article)](http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/joins-in-meteorjs-and-mongodb)
5. [Meteor Publish Composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite/)

Answer (score 1):

You will find the [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) useful for "joining" related collections even though SQL-like joins are not really practical in Mongo and Meteor. What you'll end up with is the appropriate documents and fields from each collection.

Using *myCollection* and *otherCollection* as pseudonyms for your two collections:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('pseudoJoin', {
    find: function() {
        return myCollection.find();
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(doc) {
                return otherCollection.find(
                    { _id: post.anotherObject },
                    { fields: { neededField1: 1, neededField2: 1 } });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Note that the `_id` field of the *otherCollection* will be included automatically even though it isn't in the list of fields.

**Update based on comments**

Since you're only looking to return data to a REST call you don't have to worry about cursors or reactivity.

```
var myArray = myCollection.find().fetch();
var myOtherObject = {};
var joinedArray = myArray.map(function(el){
  myOtherObject = otherCollection.findOne({ _id: el.anotherObject });
  return {
    _id: el._id,
    name: el.name,
    lastName: el.lastName,
    neededField1: myOtherObject.neededField1,
    neededField2: myOtherObject.neededField2
  }
});
console.log(joinedArray); // These should be the droids you're looking for
```

This is based on a 1:1 relation. If there are many related objects then you have to repeat the parent object to the number of children.

Comment: I already saw it even it is on my list at number 5. I just wonder if it is the best way to do it. Note that I am using rest calls...

Comment: Oh! You should mention in your question that you want to serve this up via REST because then (a) you don't need to return a reactive cursor, just a static array and (b) the answer is then to just use `.fetch()` and `.map()` to build a joined array on the server.

Comment: can you give me an example?